# Deny access to directory, deny one subdirectory and allow second subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My question has three parts to cover *everything* in regards to directory and sub-directory access.

1. How do you allow/block access to the directory that the .htaccess file is within in a way that will *not* effect sub-directories in the next two questions.
2. How do you allow access to a sub-directory inside of a parent-directory that public users do not have access to?
3. How do you disallow access to a sub-directory inside of a parent-directory that users do not have access to?

Visually the following is what I want with the .htaccess file located at *example/.htaccess*...

**example/** - Access denied.

**example/allow/** - Access allowed.

**example/disallow/** - Access denied.

Answer (score 0):

You can place these rules in `/example/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/

RewriteRule ^$ - [F]

RewriteRule ^disallow/?$ - [F,NC]
```